# Clojure (map) over map keys

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I've got a map from keywords to compass direction strings:

```
(def dirnames {:n "North", :s "South", :e "East", :w "West"})
```

I can look up names using the map as a function:

```
(dirnames :n)
;# = "North"
```

It seems to me that

```
(map dirnames [:n :s])
```

ought to return the vector

```
["North" "South"]
```

but it returns

```
[:n :s]
```

instead.  I've tried this half a dozen ways, supplying different functions in place of "dirnames" in the (map) call, and I always get the vector of keywords back.

Clearly I'm missing something basic.  What is it?

Comment: Which Clojure version(s)? I've only tried in 1.4.0 and 1.5.1, and both of those do what you want, i.e. `(map dirnames [:n :s])` evaluates to `("North" "South")`. Or replace `map` with `mapv` and you get `["North" "South"]`.

Comment: I've been working this in Light Table; and I'm seeing the results above in Light Table's "InstaREPL".  I'm seeing the correct behavior if I run the REPL as "java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main".

Comment: Seems to be a Light Table problem.

Comment: Ah, well I can't help you there :/ I don't use Light Table.

Comment: Asking Light Table to evaluate the entire module from scratch appears to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, am i misinterpreting the question:

```
user> (def dirnames {:n "North", :s "South", :e "East", :w "West"})\
#'user/dirnames

user> (map dirnames [:n :s])
("North" "South")
```

also:

```
user> (map #(dirnames %) [:n :s])
("North" "South")
user> (mapv #(dirnames %) [:n :s])
["North" "South"]
```

Comment: Wrong issue, though I'm glad to know about (mapv).  The problem isn't whether I'm getting a seq or a vector, it's that I wasn't getting the strings back, but the keywords.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you forgot some parens. Consider this function definition:

```
(defn foo [dirnames]
  map dirnames [:n :s])
```

It looks almost right, but it evaluates `map` for side effects, then `dirnames` for side effects (both of those do nothing), and then finally returns `[:n :s]`. That's the only reasonable explanation I can think of for behavior like what you're describing.

Comment: Turns out the code was right, but I'd confused the REPL I was working with.  I think a var was bound differently than I realized.  Good lesson.

Comment: Good guess for this question.